# Как работает данный кусок упорядочивания нитей в OMP

Tags: c++, openmp

есть данный ниже кусок кода, я не могу понять почему она работает.. - нити выводятся в обратном порядке:

```
int main()
{

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(12)
    {
        int n = omp_get_num_threads();
        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
#pragma omp barrier
            {
                if (i == omp_get_thread_num())
                {
#pragma omp critical
                    printf("Hello World... from thread = %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

По сути как я понимаю, так как FOR не распараллеливается то for попадает как экземпляр в каждую нить. Дальше все нити со своим for - ом доходят до барьера. После барьера все нити получается бегут вниз. И тогда почему все нити выводятся в упорядоченном (от большего к меньшему) виде, если после барьера любая нить теоретически может попасть на участок critical и распечататься?

Спасибо

Comment: а чему равен OMP_NUM_THREADS ? Есть предположение что у тебя просто запускается один поток из-за чего и такое поведение

Comment: @Arenoros, запускается на 12 потоков по умолчанию. Добавил правку - явное определение кол-ва потоков. Все также работает.

Comment: Причем , если закомментить строчку с prgma omp critical, то программа продолжает выводить в правильно порядке (в порядке убывания), если удалить барьер, то программа начинается рандомно печатать нить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каждая нить в своем коде содержит не один барьер, а 12. (Поскольку `#pragma omp barrier` находится внутри цикла.)

Т.е. каждая нить доходит до первого барьера, ждет у барьера остальные, стартует...
Только одна нить что-то печатает (та которая имеет наибольший номер), остальные сразу утыкаются в следюищей барьер. Этот второй барьер может быть преодолен только после того, как все потоки начнут 2-ю итерацию цикла. Т.е. печать 1-го сообщения будет завершена.

Фактически данный барьер гарантирует, что итерации цикла будут происходить синхронно во всех потоках. (Ценой ожидания отстающих на барьере.)

Описанный Вами порядок работы, соотвествует случаю, когда барьер находится вне цикла. (Т.е. только одн на поток.)

Comment: да, видимо так и работает, спасибо за разъяснение. Только один вопрос - как барьеры из разных потоков общаются между собой, если у каждой нити он свой? Может хотя бы ссылку на доскональную документацию дадите. Даже на англоязычных ресурсах, кроме того, что барьер стопует все нити, ничего не написано. Спасибо !

Comment: @KamilNHOT  Если вас интересуют детали механизма реализации - то они нигде не описаны, и могут существенно отличаться для реализаций разных производителей (разных компиляторов, разных библиотек... ). Наиболее полная спецификация: https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5.0.pdf (Но это не учебник, поэтому для целей обучения не рекомендую. Но спорные вопросы можно уточнить.) Ничего кроме того, что все нити ждут - там тоже  не сказано.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь